# Parse the JSON String efficiently and in a clean way

Tags: java, json, string, parsing

In my below code, `colData` stores `JSON String`. Sample example for colData-

```
{"lv":[{"v":{"price":70.0,"userId":419},"cn":3},
       {"v":{"price":149.99,"userId":419},"cn":3},
       {"v":{"price":54.95,"userId":419},"cn":3}],
 "lmd":20130206212543}
```

Now I am trying to match `id` value with `userId` value in the above `JSON String`. I am getting `id` value from a different source.
Meaning if `id` value is `419` then in the above JSON String `userId` value should also be `419`. And in the JSON String, it might be possible there are lot of `userId values` so all the `userId` values should be matching with `id`. If any of them doesn't matches then log the exception.

So I was trying something like this-

```
final int id = generateRandomId(random);

for (String str : colData) {
    if (!isJSONValid(str, id)) {
        // log the exception here
        LOG.error("Invalid JSON String " +str+ "with id" +id);
    }
}

public boolean isJSONValid(final String str, final int id) {
    boolean valid = false;
    try {
        final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
        final JSONArray geodata = obj.getJSONArray("lv");
        final int n = geodata.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            final JSONObject person = geodata.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject  menu = person.getJSONObject("v");
            if(menu.getInt("userId") == id) {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

As per my understanding it looks like I can make `isJSONValid` method more cleaner. In my above `isJSONValid` method as I am repeating some stuff which I shouldn't be doing. Can anyone help me out how to make this more cleaner if I have missed anything. I will be able to learn some more stuff. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you only need one match to make it good, or only one mismatch to make it bad?  If the former, `break` after setting valid to true.  If the latter, you need to reverse the sense of valid (and the if test) and `break` after setting invalid the first time.

Comment: As soon as it is finding any mismatch, I need to log the exception. I got confused with the way you described. Can you explain that with example? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Think about it -- if you require everything to match then the first *mismatch* means you can quit and report "bad".  If you make it all the way through it's "good".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize `valid = true` and set it to false when you find a non-valid `userId` and immediately fail:

```
public boolean isJSONValid(final String str, final int id) {
    boolean valid = true;
    try {
        final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
        final JSONArray geodata = obj.getJSONArray("lv");
        final int n = geodata.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            final JSONObject person = geodata.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject  menu = person.getJSONObject("v");
            if(menu.getInt("userId") != id) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

This way you iterate through all array's elements only if all are valid, which is the only case you actually have to.

Comment: Thanks yair for the suggestion. It makes sense now. Apart from this fix everything looks good right in my code? Meaning whatever I did is right? As I was thinking, I am repeating some lines of code here.

Comment: @Nevzz03 I don't see any reapeated line of code... the only thing I'd change in your code would be using of String.format to log excepion, and maybe creating constants from Strings like `userId`, `v` and `lv`

Comment: I don't see any repeating lines except for using `getJSONObject` a few times, but you use it for specific properties in your JSON. Unless this intends to be some utility method designated for general JSON queries, your code looks striaghtfoward and simple. It took reading once your code (and your doumentation (-; ) to help you so its quite clean.

Comment: @dantuch you are, actually, more accurate than me :).

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestion. Appreciated your help.